# Good MapPoint Add-ins resources

Tags: add-in, mappoint

I am trying to develop an add-ins for MapPoint (with forms, and other feature) and I am trying to get some informations on how to do this. So far I don't have much info.

Does anyone know a good site or have some examples of add-ins for developing for MapPoint ?

Either language is fine with me, but I personally prefer VB.Net.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you found http://www.MapForums.com yet?  That is where we mainly hang out. The owner (Eric Frost) also runs http://www.MP2KMag.com which has more articles.

I have a few demos on my site ( http://www.mapping-tools.com ) but these were cross-published at MP2KMag.com

for .NET MapPoint programming, then Chandu Thota's book is the best book around. Yes it refers to an older version and most of the examples use C#; but it gives you a good run through of all the tricks and traps.

Comment: Thanks. I knew about MapForums and MP2KMag, but somehow I don't really like the format of it. I'll take a look at your site. Thanks for the book.

Comment: For commercial add-ins I also use AddinExpress (a commercial third party library/wizard). Although in theory you don't need it, I find it makes end user installations more reliable.